# How to limit the number of selection of a Multi-Select Filter?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, jasperserver

**How to limit the number of selection of a Multi-Select Filter ?**

- Report is generated using Jasper Soft Studio v6.0.1 and published on Jasper Server v6.0.1.
- DBMS: MongoDB

Example : The filter has 10 values. The user must be able to select atmost 5 values from these 10 values at a time. If he selects more than 5 values, he should be prompted with an error.

Comment: did you have the jasper code checked out at your end?

Comment: Nope. So do I need to download the entire Jasper Soft Studio Source code ? Ok I'll do that. What then?

Comment: Then you have debug the code from where javascript code is for multi-select and then there you need to modify the code as in the below link..